# Gravity applies after a short delay. Why?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I use Instantiate to spawn an object. But when it appears first it goes down slowly and then it get its max speed. On a second thought i think it is how physics work in real life. But I want it to get the max speed as soon as it spawned. Is this even something possible? I am using Unity's physics btw.

Comment: Not really giving us a lot to work with here :-) Anyway there shouldn't be a delay, it's possible the body is sleeping so you could call `Rigidbody::WakeUp` when your object is instantiated. Failing that i'm not sure how of the unity api is exposed for debugging, but if you can find where the velocity of a rigidbody is integrated then you should be able to trace the call stack back to the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to bypass the actual physics engine i.e. get non-realistic behavior, one way would be to mark your object's `RigidBody` as being `kinematic` and alter your object's `transform.position` manually during updates (while taking into consideration the delta time between frames), making it move downwards at a constant speed. Note that this will mess with other parts of the physics engine, such as collisions.

If you still want to use the physics engine, one quick way to experiment and see if it works for you is to do something like `RigidBody.AddForce(0, 0, force, ForceMode.Impulse);` when the object that falls gets instantiated. `force` is a `float` and defines the size of the force i.e. how hard the object gets pushed down. The call to `AddForce` above assumes the z axis is the vertical axis, I forgot which one's which in Unity.

Depending on your use case this may work for you. I have no idea what your use case is. Maybe you don't want your spawned object to bounce when it hits the ground, and dealing with regular phyiscs and forces will make it bounce. In that case just move it down manually.

More info [here](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody.AddForce.html).

As a side note, unless the object's fall is meaningful, have you considered spawning it directly on the ground?

Comment: enough information for me. thank you

Answer (score 0):

If it is a rigidbody you can add a force on instantiation.

Comment: Or just not use default physics. They weren't meant to be used like this.